# Android Studio: White Space Formatting Strategy Factory error

Tags: android, groovy, intellij-idea, compiler-errors

When this error first accured i was working on a project, i tried to create a new java class but no matter how many times i hit the ok button it just wouldn't create the file and give me that error.

Than when i opened the error log it said there was an exception in the groovy plugin so i disabled it and than enabled it again but it didn't help too. I deleted the whole project and tried to create a new one. But it didn't create a new project either. It just kept giving me this error.

Is there anyone who knows how to fix it ? In couple of days i am supposed to present my thesis so i am in a hurry.

this is the ss of the error;
[image: error]

This is what i get in the description of the error.

```
Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/intellij/psi/formatter/WhiteSpaceFormattingStrategyFactory: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/intellij/psi/formatter/WhiteSpaceFormattingStrategyFactory
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Illegal UTF8 string in constant pool in class file com/intellij/psi/formatter/WhiteSpaceFormattingStrategyFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader._defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:195)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.defineClass(UrlClassLoader.java:191)
    at com.intellij.util.lang.UrlClassLoader.findClass(UrlClassLoader.java:152)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at com.intellij.psi.formatter.FormattingDocumentModelImpl.<init>(FormattingDocumentModelImpl.java:53)
    at com.intellij.psi.formatter.FormattingDocumentModelImpl.createOn(FormattingDocumentModelImpl.java:73)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.groovy.formatter.GroovyFormattingModelBuilder.createModel(GroovyFormattingModelBuilder.java:75)
    at com.intellij.formatting.CoreFormatterUtil.buildModel(CoreFormatterUtil.java:48)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeFormatterFacade.doProcessRange(CodeFormatterFacade.java:128)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeFormatterFacade.processRange(CodeFormatterFacade.java:95)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeFormatterFacade.processElement(CodeFormatterFacade.java:91)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeStyleManagerImpl.reformat(CodeStyleManagerImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeStyleManagerImpl.reformat(CodeStyleManagerImpl.java:91)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.format(Template.java:956)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.instantiate(Template.java:853)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$500(Template.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$3.startElement(Template.java:486)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.executeRecipeFile(Template.java:473)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$300(Template.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$2.startElement(Template.java:449)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.processFile(Template.java:419)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.doRender(Template.java:273)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.access$000(Template.java:92)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template$1.run(Template.java:252)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$4.run(WriteCommandAction.java:178)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$Simple.run(WriteCommandAction.java:168)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:117)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.access$000(WriteCommandAction.java:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:85)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.runWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:175)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:249)
    at com.android.tools.idea.templates.Template.render(Template.java:235)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.performFinishingActions(ConfigureAndroidProjectPath.java:121)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard$WizardCompletionAction.run(DynamicWizard.java:621)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.RunResult.run(RunResult.java:38)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:118)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:984)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$2.run(WriteCommandAction.java:115)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.impl.CommandProcessorImpl.executeCommand(CommandProcessorImpl.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.performWriteCommandAction(WriteCommandAction.java:112)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.access$000(WriteCommandAction.java:33)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction$1.run(WriteCommandAction.java:80)
    at com.intellij.openapi.command.WriteCommandAction.execute(WriteCommandAction.java:85)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.doFinishAction(DynamicWizard.java:428)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DialogWrapperHost$FinishAction.doAction(DialogWrapperHost.java:323)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper$DialogWrapperAction.actionPerformed(DialogWrapper.java:1719)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$2.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:184)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:229)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport$4.run(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.awt.WaitDispatchSupport.enter(WaitDispatchSupport.java:227)
    at java.awt.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:1084)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl$MyDialog.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:787)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.impl.DialogWrapperPeerImpl.show(DialogWrapperPeerImpl.java:463)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.showAndGetOk(DialogWrapper.java:1557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.ui.DialogWrapper.show(DialogWrapper.java:1524)
    at com.android.tools.idea.wizard.DynamicWizard.show(DynamicWizard.java:463)
    at com.android.tools.idea.actions.AndroidNewProjectAction.actionPerformed(AndroidNewProjectAction.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.ex.ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware(ActionUtil.java:164)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter$1.run(ActionMenuItem.java:266)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.FocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(FocusManagerImpl.java:926)
    at com.intellij.openapi.wm.impl.IdeFocusManagerImpl.runOnOwnContext(IdeFocusManagerImpl.java:124)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem$ActionTransmitter.actionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:236)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
    at com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.impl.ActionMenuItem.fireActionPerformed(ActionMenuItem.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.doClick(BegMenuItemUI.java:512)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI.access$300(BegMenuItemUI.java:44)
    at com.intellij.ui.plaf.beg.BegMenuItemUI$MyMouseInputHandler.mouseReleased(BegMenuItemUI.java:532)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:697)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:520)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:335)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Comment: I would first try resetting the settings, if doesn't help - reinstalling AS.

Comment: Done that, still getting the same error. I deleted the .AndroidStudio and .AndroidStudioBeta folders, but still the same error.

Comment: hmm, hard to say what causes this error. Do you have any non-latin symbols in the installation/settings path?

Comment: I don't think so, anyways i just uninstalled the As and reinstalled it as you said :D it helped, i hope i will not get the same problem again. Since i just used the general solution of reinstalling, should i delete the question ?

Comment: I haven't found any similar questions on SO, so yours may be of help to other people encountering the same problem. I would rather leave it. Do you mind me posting the answer so that we close the issue?

Comment: Yes that ould be great. And thank yo for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Experiments have showed resetting settings doesn't help, but the issue is resolved by reinstalling AS.